# How does one have menu of links to different React.js applications

Tags: reactjs

I want to have a create a sidebar component using React.js with links to different react applications. I know how to create an unordered list of links. Issue is how does one provide a link to a react application and when the link is clicked it dynamically puts that specific react application onto the screen?

Comment: Can't you just use regular links? i.e. they take the user to a new URL? 

Otherwise can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: I want to have one main react application that has a sidebar of links to different react applications then one main part where the the react app is generated into when the user clicks the link.

Comment: Sounds more like rendering different components rather than entirely new react apps. React Router is the defacto routing solution currently

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start

Answer (score 1):

You can use [React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/) to render different components when users click on different links. These components can represent entire sub-apps if you need them to.

Comment: I will try to do it with react router and get back. Thanks.